How do I make Flycheck not create a second frame?
I am learning Lean4, and lean4-mode uses Flycheck. If I only have one frame and one window, and I edit this Lean program in that window,
import Lean.Elab.Command
elab "#check_syntax " t:term : command => do Lean.logInfo m!"{repr t.raw}"
#check_syntax 42 + "foo"

then moving the point to the line '#check_syntax 42 + "foo"' makes Lean.logInfo output an error message that is 19 lines long, and Flycheck displays it in the buffer "Flycheck error messages"...
The problem is that in this case - one frame, one window, long error message - Flycheck always displays the buffer "Flycheck error messages" in a second frame. How do I change that?
